# PORQUE NO ME AGREGA CUANDO EJECUTO EL CONTROLADOR

Tags: php, api, phpmyadmin

### Esta es mi conexión

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class Conexion
{
    
    public function conectar(){

        $localhost = "localhost";
        $database = "enfoque_store";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$database",$user,$password);

        return $link;
    }
}

?>
```

---

### Esto es mi modulo

```
<?php

require_once "Conexion.php";

/**
 * 
 */
class Datos extends Conexion
{
    
    #USUARIOS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function createUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, password, role, mail) VALUES (:usuario, :password, :role, :mail)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datosModel["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":role", $datosModel["role"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $datosModel["mail"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "registro exitoso";
            return true;
        }else{
            echo "no se pudo hacer el registro";
            return false;
        }
    }

?>
```

---

### Este es mi controlador que no me agrega a los usuarios

```
<?php

require_once "ModeloJson.php";

/**
 * 
 */
class ControllerJson
{
    
    public function createUsuarioController($usuario, $password, $role, $mail){

        $datosController = array("usuario"=>$usuario,
              "password"=>$password,
              "role"=>$role,
              "mail"=>$mail);

ERROR--> $respuesta = Datos::createUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");
        return $respuesta;

    }
    
}

$obj = new ControllerJson();
$obj->createUsuarioController("luz", "1234", "cliente", "luz@curso.com");

?>
```

---

### EL ERROR QUE ME SALES ES ESTE EN LA LINEA 18 DE MI CONTROLADOR

```
http://localhost/api_enfoque_store/ControllerJson.php
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method
> Datos::createUsuarioModel() cannot be called statically in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api_enfoque_store\ControllerJson.php:18 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\api_enfoque_store\ControllerJson.php(26): ControllerJson->createUsuarioController('luz', '1234', 'cliente',
> 'luz@curso.com') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api_enfoque_store\ControllerJson.php on line 18

Comment: Esta línea: `Datos::createUsuarioModel` debe ser así: `Datos->createUsuarioModel....` desde el momento en que dicho método no es `static` entonces no hace sentido que lo invoques de la primer forma mostrada

Answer (score 1):

El error es por que este llamado:

```
Datos::createUsuarioModel.....
```

Solo sería válido, si el método en su definición fuera *static* de esta forma:

```
public static function createUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla){
```

Así entonces no vas a requerir una instancia de dicha clase y podrás usar dicho método.

Luego entonces una **posible** solución sería:

1. En la clase *ControllerJson* puedes generar la instancia de `Datos` así:

   ```
    public function createUsuarioController($usuario, $password, $role, $mail)
    {
        $instanciaDatos = new Datos();



        $datosController = array("usuario"=>$usuario,
            "password"=>$password,
            "role"=>$role,
            "mail"=>$mail);

        $respuesta = $instanciaDatos->createUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");
        return $respuesta;

    }
   ```

**Enlaces de referencia**

- [Declaración de métodos estáticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static)